# Auto index rows using CSS is not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, css

I am trying to auto index first cell in each row using CSS. However the number in the first row starts with 2. What is the change I need to make in CSS to start the counter from 1?

```css
table {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{userFullName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{userFullName}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the initial counter on `tbody` instead of `table`.

```
tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}
```

```css
tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

tbody tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{userFullName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{userFullName}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting negative value to `rowNumber`

```css
table {
  counter-reset: -rowNumber;
}

table tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
}
```

```html
<table id="1234">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{userFullName}}</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{userFullName}}</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```